# List<Enum> in Aggregates EntityFramework CodeFirst

Tags: c#, entity-framework, enums

I was initially using Enum in aggregates which happened to be working fine for me, but now when i changed the property to List , i find that the values are not being saved or retrieved in the database, I thought that the CodeFirst would create a separate table for the List and map the rows there, but that isn't the case, the values are neither being stored nor retreived.

Agg:

```
public class Trainee: Entity
    {
        public int TraineeId { get; set; }

        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Age { get; set;}
        public virtual List<CoursesTypes> CoursesOpted { get; set; }

    }
```

Enum:

```
 public enum CoursesTypes
    {
        PHP,
        Networking,
    }
```

Comment: There is a same question with an answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28429945/ef-property-of-type-listenum-not-created-in-db?noredirect=1#

Answer (score 0):

It's my understanding that enums are stored as an integer when they're a standard property of an object. But I'm not sure what happens when you're using a collection of enums as a property; that doesn't feel like it should be possible.

This link should give you more info on enum support in Entity Framework (http://www.itorian.com/2012/09/enum-support-code-first-in-entity.html).

Incidently, you shouldn't need to derive from Entity if you're using DbSet and code first and I'd suggest using

```
public virtual ICollection<CourseTypes> CourseOpted {get; set;}
```

for the signature of your collection properties.

Answer (score 0):

Use Flag Enum. You dont need any additional tables. It is much more faster.

In your model you can do

```
var person = new Trainee();
p.CoursesOpted.Add(CoursesTypes.PHP);
p.CoursesOpted.Add(CoursesTypes.PHP);
```

... which is wrong. With flag you will do like that

```
p.CoursesOpted = CoursesTypes.PHP | CoursesTypes.Networking;
```

http://blog.falafel.com/entity-framework-enum-flags/