# EF property of type List<enum> not created in db

Tags: c#, entity-framework, enums

I'm developing an ASP.NET MVC5 application using code first EF. My code:

```
public enum Language : byte
{
    [Display(Name = "Turkmen")]
    TKM = 1,
    [Display(Name = "Russian")]
    RUS = 2,
    [Display(Name = "Chineese")]
    CHN = 3,
    [Display(Name = "English")]
    ENG = 4
}
```

And my model class is:

```
public class Person
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int PersonID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Surname { get; set; }

    public virtual List<Enums.Language> Languages { get; set; }

    public Person()
    {
        Languages = new List<Enums.Language>();
    }
}
```

After I build application and Update-Database in package manager console in VS 2013 I can not find a reference table for Persons languages. I thought a table with a name `Person_Languages` (or similar) with `PersonID` and `LanguageID` should be created. What did I wrong or missed?

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18074737/listenum-in-aggregates-entityframework-codefirst
And: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15045303/ef-5-codefirst-enum-collection-not-generated-in-database

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I can't clearly reference my response but: an enum is not a class so it can't be an entity.

In you case you have to create a language class:

```
public class CLanguage
{
    public Int32 Id { get; set; }
    public Language Lang { get; set; }
}
```

and then:

```
public class Person
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int PersonID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Surname { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<CLanguage> Languages { get; set; }

    public Person()
    {
        Languages = new List<CLanguage>();
    }
}
```

Please note the use of `ICollection` instead of List for compliance.

You may also want to use the enum property as PK.

```
public class CLanguage
{
    [Key]    
    public Language Lang { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 15):

Use Flag Enum. You don't need any additional tables. It is much more faster.

In your model you can do

```
var person = new Person();
p.Languages.Add(Language.TKM);
p.Languages.Add(Language.TKM); // Add the same language twice
```

... which is wrong. With flag you will do like that

```
p.Languages = Language.TKM | Language.RUS;
```

http://blog.falafel.com/entity-framework-enum-flags/

Comment: note that by doing so you limit the number of codable languages to 32 (int) or 64 (long). Of course nobody (or not everybody) on earth speaks 32 languagues, but may be 100000 persons speak more than 32 languages.